# What are the differences between these three patterns of "class" definitions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js, coffeescript

Are there any important/subtle/significant differences under the hood when choosing to use one of these four patterns over the others?  And, are there any differences between the them when "instantiated" via `Object.create()` vs the `new` operator?

1) The pattern that `CoffeeScript` uses when translating "class" definitions:

```
Animal = (function() {

  function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Animal.prototype.move = function(meters) {
    return alert(this.name + (" moved " + meters + "m."));
  };

  return Animal;

})();
```

and

2) The pattern that `Knockout` seems to promote:

```
var DifferentAnimal = function(name){

    var self = this;

    self.name = name;

    self.move = function(meters){
        return alert(this.name + (" moved " + meters + "m."));
    };

}
```

and

3) a similar, simple pattern I've often seen:

```
var DifferentAnimalWithClosure = function(name){

    var name = name;

    var move = function(meters){

    };

    return {name:name, move:move};

}
```

and

4) The pattern that `Backbone` promotes:

```
var OneMoreAnimal= ClassThatAlreadyExists.extend({

    name:'',
    move:function(){}

});
```

**Update 1:** Changed pattern #2 and added pattern #3 in response to Elias' response // minor formatting

Comment: Knockout's pattern doesn't actually make classes that are prototypable or extensible.

Comment: Knockout does not require using any specific pattern.  The pattern above is not what we normally use in our documentation (returning the anonymous object, rather than just letting it be `this` where you can still use a prototype).

Comment: Waleed - this was the type of under-the-hood differences I was hoping to uncover - thanks much.

Comment: RP - my mistake in the original post...have edited it since to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to be clear: JS doesn't know of classes, just objects and custom, self-defined constructor functions, but that's besides the point. 
To answer your question in short: yes, there are some small and even some fairly large differences between the various ways of creating a new object you're posting here.

*CoffeeScript:*
This is actually the most clear-cut and traditional way to create your own constructor, but it has been *"optimized"* in the sense that it's been ready set-up to use (optional) closure variables. 
Basically, what this code does, is use an IIFE, to wrap both the constructor definition *and* the proptotype method assignments in their own, private scope, that returns a reference to the new constructor. It's just clean, simple JS, no different from what you might write yourself.

*Knockout:*
Now this threw me a little, because to me, at least, the snippet you provide looks either like part of a module pattern, or a power constructor. But since you're not using `strict mode`, omitting the `new` would still make for dangerous situations, and since the entire function goes trough the trouble of creating a new instance of `DifferentAnimal`, only to *then* construct a second object literal, assigning all properties of `DifferentAnimal` to that secondary object, I'd say you're missing something. Because, truth be told, omitting the last `return {};` statement here, would probably make no difference at all. Plus: as you can see, you're declaring a method (`move`) in what is, in essence, a constructor. This means that *every* instance will be assigned its own function object `move`, rather then getting it from the prototype. 
In short: have another close look at where you got this snippet from, and double-check if this is the full version, because if it is, I can only see arguments *against* this.

Using a variable, defined inside the constructor is simply: a closure, suppose your properties have a distinct initial state, determined by some arguments, passed to that constructor:

```
function MyConstructor(param)
{
     var paramInit = param/2;//or something
     this.p = paramInit;//this property can change later on, so:
     this.reInit = function()
     {//this method HAS to be inside constructor, every instance needs its own method
         this.p = paramInit;//var paramInit can't, it's local to this scope
     };
}
var foo = new MyConstructor(10);
console.log(foo.p);//5
foo.p = 'hi';
console.log(foo.p);//hi
foo.reInit();
console.log(foo.p);//5
console.log(foo.paramInit);//undefined, not available outside object: it's a pseudo-private property
```

That's all there is too it, really. When you see ppl using `var that = this;` or something, that's often to create a reference to the main object that is available anywhere, without having to deal with the headaches of `this` (what does `this` reference? What should the method do when applied to an object *other* than the one it was originally intended for? etcetera...)

*Backbone:*
Here, we're dealing with another case: extending objects (IE: using methods, properties of either an existing *"class"* (constructor) or a particular instance) is not the same as simply creating an object. 
As you well know, JS objects can be assigned new properties at any given time. Those properties can be removed, too. Sometimes, prototype properties can be redefined on the instance itself (masking the prototypal behaviour) etc... So it all depends on what you want the resulting object (the newly created object, that extends the given instance) to look like: do you want it to take all properties from the instance, or do you want both objects to use the same prototype somewhere down the line?
Both of these things can be achieved by using simple JS, too, but they just take a bit more effort to write yourself. However, if you write, for example:

```
function Animal(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.eat= function()
{
    console.log(this.name + ' is eating');
};
```

That could be deemed the equivalent of writing:

```
var Animal = Object.extend({name:'',eat:function()
{
    console.log(this.name + ' is eating');
}});
```

A lot shorter, but lacking the constructor.

*`new` vs `Object.create`*
Well, that's an easy one: `Object.create` just is a lot more powerful that `new`: you can define prototype methods, properties (including weather or not they are enumerable, writeable etc...) right at the time you need to create an object, instead of having to write a constructor and a prototype, or create an object literal and mess around with all those `Object.defineProperty` lines.
The downsides: Some people *still* aren't using ECMA5 compliant browsers (IE8 is still not quite dead). In my experience: it does become quite hard to debug sizeable scripts after a while: though I tend to use power-constructors more than I do regular constructors, I still have them defined at the very top of my script, with distinct, clear and quite descriptive names, whereas object-literals are things I just create *"on-the-fly"*. Using `Object.create`, I noticed I tend to create objects that are really a little too complex to qualify as actual object literals, as though they are object literals:

```
//fictional example, old:
var createSomething = (function()
{
    var internalMethod = function()
    {//method for new object
        console.log(this.myProperty || '');
    };
    return function(basedOn)
    {
        var prop, returnVal= {};
        returnVal.myProperty = new Date();
        returnVal.getCreated = internalMethod;//<--shared by all instances, thx to closure
        if (!basedOn || !(basedOn instanceof Object))
        {//no argument, or argument is not an object:
            return returnVal;
        }
        for (prop in basedOn)
        {//extend instance, passed as argument
            if (basedOn.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !== '_extends')
            {
                returnVal[prop] = basedOn[prop];
            }
        }
        returnVal._extends = basedOn;//<-- ref as sort-of-prototype
        return returnVal;
    };
}());
```

Now this is pretty verbose, but I've got my basic constructor ready, and I can use it to extend an existing instance, too. It might seem less verbose to simply write:

```
var createSomething = Object.create(someObject, {getCreated:function()
{
    console.log(this.myProperty);
},
myProperty:new Date()});
```

But IMO, this makes it harder on you do keep track of what object is created where (mainly because `Object.create` is an expression, and *will not be hoisted*.
Ah well, that's far from a conclusive argument of course: both have their pro's and con's: I prefer using module patters, closures and power constructors, if you don't that's just fine.

Hope this cleared up a thing or 2 for you.

Comment: First, thanks for the awesomely detailed response...second, apologies for my example on number 2; I meant to create local variables instead of hanging them off of self - eg, "var name =" instead of "self.name =" and likewise specifying the closure'd variables in the return statement ...  I will update the original post, but any additional insight after that clarification is appreciated!

Comment: @user1889765: updated the knockout bit to reflect on the local vars. When it comes to returning the closure variables: you're no longer dealing with a tried 'n true constructor: you're dealing with a module . Which is just a huge closure, and needs to return those closure vars in order to create the desired _exposure_. Just look at the src of jQuery for a real-life example of this

Answer (score 3):

The first example puts the move function in the prototype which will be shared between all Animal instances.

The second example creates a new move function for every the animal instance.

The third example generates a Animal class with the move function in the prototype similar to the first example but with allot less code.
(In your example the name is also shared between all instances, which you probably don't want)

Putting the function in the prototype makes instantiating Animals faster, and because of the way JIT engines work even the execution of the function is faster.

Comment: Another great under-the-hood discovery re: performance gains via shared functionality across instances. Thanks again.

Comment: This answer contains some useful points, but the description of the third example is slightly off. In #3, the function returns a new object with `name` & `move` properties, but does not assign the constructor property or a prototype to it. It looks like you could create a new DifferentAnimalWithClosure instance with `var frog = new DifferentAnimalWithClosure('Roger');` and you can, but if you later ran `frog instanceof DifferentAnimalWithClosure;`, you'd get `false` back. Patterns like #1 & #2 would assign "DifferentAnimalWithClosure"-ness to the new object.