# setTimeout and this - simplest solution?

Tags: javascript

As we know , `setTimeout` is not working correctly with `this` becuase it runs in a global scope ( and `this` will be `window`)

But I've made a simple [**test**](http://jsbin.com/uceqih/2/edit) :

Just wrap it with function :

```
var o={}
o.a=1;
o.m=function (){alert(this.a);}


setTimeout( 
  function (){
               o.m()  ;
             }

    ,100);
```

And it does alert `1`.

Am I missing something here ? why none of the answer suggests this solution ?  does  it behave different ?

p.s. : for those who intereseted here is a demo where it fails :

```
var o={}
o.a=1;
o.m=function (){alert(this.a);}


setTimeout( o.m   ,100); //undefined
```

Comment: `o.m` is merely "referring" to the function, not "calling" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to `bind()` the scope of the anonymous function.

```
var o = {};
o.a = 1;

setTimeout(function (){
    alert(this.a);
}.bind(o), 1000);
```

While your answer produces the same results, it's not accessing the scope of `o` from within the anonymous function.  It's merely calling a function of the global object `o`.

Your reference to `this.a` is from within the scope of `o`.

Comment: I know. but myne is working also.why is doesnt being mentioned anywhere ?

Comment: Yours is not referencing the scope of o from within the anonymous function.  It's merely calling a method of the global object `o`

Comment: mmmm so X.method() will always consider [this] as X.... while using `this` without "object holder"  should be used with bind.call.apply etc.....right ?

Comment: Yes.  `this` references the scope of the method.  In the case of `X.method()`, `this` references `X`.

Comment: Well i thought that even in pattern of `X.method` , `this` will refer to the global. and _that_ was my mistake. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing *closures*. Your callback function will have access to `o`, even if it's not been declared globally, as long as the callback was defined in a scope that *did* have access to `o`.

JS can't GC `o`, because the callback function still references it, hence your snippet works

Example:

```
(function()
{
    var scope = {};//an empty object
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(typeof scope);
    },1000);
}());
console.log(scope);
```

Here, you'll see `undefined` being logged, and (about) a second later, you'll see `{}` followed by `object` appear.
Whereas:

```
var foo = {bar: 'foobar',
           callback: function()
           {
               console.log(this);
           }
};
setTimeout(foo.callback, 1000);
console.log(foo.callback());
```

Will first log the object, referenced by `foo`, but then a second later, the same function object will log the global object because (as you say correctly), the function reference is invoked in the global context. The only way to avoid this is to use `bind`, or create another closure (but that would take us too far ATM).

I have gone into more detail on JS's ad-hoc context binding and reference resolving [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500101/objects-and-functions-in-javascript/13500475#13500475), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789559/what-are-the-differences-between-these-three-patterns-of-class-definitions-in/13790503#13790503), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640216/memory-management-of-javascript-array/12640609#12640609), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213074/what-makes-my-class-js-so-fast/14336037#14336037) and so on, and so forth

Answer (score 0):

"this" is defined differently in different scopes, whereas you only defined "o" globally.